# BigDecimal for bignumber does not work correctly in float value

Tags: java, bigdecimal

There is a `BigDecimal` datatype in java.
When I declare the number 5190000000 as BigDecimal like this:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(5190000000L * 1.0F);
```

, it is excited and the following output is seen:

```
Output:
5190000128
```

while I ommit the F as float value, it is correct like this:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(5190000000L * 1.0);

Output:
5190000000
```

What is it? and how does F parameter make mistake?I really confused!!!!

**EDIT**

The version of jdk is 1.8

Answer (score 3):

Before the `BigDecimal` is constructed, the expression inside the brackets needs to be evaluated first.

So, `5190000000 * 1.0F` gets evaluated to a `float` value, but that value is not exactly 5190000000. Why? Because 5190000000 cannot be accurately represented in `float`. Some precision is lost already, before the `BigDecimal` is created. Therefore, the output you see is not accurate.

In the second case, `5190000000 * 1.0` gets evaluated to a `double`, and `double` has enough precision to represent 5190000000 accurately. Why does it get evaluated to a `double` this time?, you might ask. Because `1.0F` is a float literal, and `1.0` is a double literal. And that decides the type of the expression.

To get an accurate value, use the string constructor:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("5190000000");
bd = bd.multiply(BigDecimal.ONE); // if you insist on multiplying it by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never create a `BigDecimal` using the `double` constructor.  As the `double` (or `float`, in this case) you are passing in is imprecise to begin with, that imprecision will be reflected in the `BigDecimal`.

It is recommended that you either use the `String` or `long` constructors for `BigDecimal`, or the `valueOf` factory method, to initialize a `BigDecimal`, as these are more likely to retain the precision you need.

Comment: I need to float value, how i initialize the bigdecimal with the float value?

Comment: Would you send some example?

Comment: You can't.  The number in your `float` is too big to be represented precisely, and for that reason the `BigDecimal` will never have the correct value when you create it in this way.

Comment: How do I fix my problem? What is your idea?

Comment: My idea is to not use `float` for numbers that big.  Use a `double` instead.

Comment: What is valueOf factory method?

Comment: Some time  I need to float value for example 2.5

Comment: You can fit 2.5 into a `double` quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. The expression `5190000000 * 1.0F` is evaluated as a float, which has only 6 to 7 decimal digits precision.

Actually, the value you eventually get is accurate to 7 digits.

Answer (score 0):

**reason**
- The construction method of BigDecimal, the parameter type is double.
- So, your first code will be make implicit convert by compiler that will make some problem of lose accuracy.
- But, your second code '1.0' the type default is double, so that is correct.
- Other thing, the int type the max value is 2147483647, your set parameter is 5190000000 that will be make compile error.

Comment: I need the float value, How do i fix problem?